# How to create a sprite from an image loaded in Loader()?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, loader, flashdevelop

I'm loading a background image via the Loader() class and wanted to know if there's a way to create a sprite from that loaded image?

I'm wanting to put a function in an external class file to put the image in the loader and then call the class to create a sprite from the loaded image. I'm not even sure this is possible.

Note: I'm using flashdevelop and no timeline.

Comment: You can treat the Loader instance as a sprite (or more generally, as a display object) - ie: set its x,y,rotation,alpha etc - but you cant convert a bitmap image into a Sprite class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the loader object as a display object or you can access the Bitmap object in the loader and add that to a sprite.

```
 var loader:Loader = new Loader();
 loader.load(new URLRequest(filename)); 
 addChild(loader);

 loader.x = 100;
 loader.y = 200;
 //so on
```

To get access to the bitmap and bitmapdata loaded just add an event listener and access them.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest(filename));  

private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
{
   var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
   var loadedBitmap:Bitmap = loaderInfo.content as Bitmap;

   var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
   sprite.addChild(loadedBitmap);

   addChild(sprite);

   sprite.x = 100;
   sprite.y = 200;
   //so on

}
```